# fatal: repository not found in xcode and terminal. Works with iSVN

Tags: ios, xcode, git, repository

I am partially unable to connect to my repository.

We have a local server set up with Subversion. I am able to push and pull with iSVN so serverside is ok.

Whenever I try to push or pull with Xcode or Terminal it shows "repository not found error" or "Connection Failed" when trying to pull from repo when creating new project.

**What have I tried:**

1) Xcode ->create new project->Create Git repository -> Add to new server. 
Shows "Connection Failed"

2) Assigned repository in Xcode->preferences, Added remote in Xcode ->Source Control->Working Copies->Configure "projectName". When I try to commit,push or pull I get prompted for username, password, after inputing I get  error "fatal repository not found".

3) Create empty folder, add some file in it

`git init`
`git add .`

```
git commit -m 'first commit'

git remote add origin 'http://192.168.1.150/something/something'

git push origin, git pull origin
```

Asks for username, password after that same fatal error repository not found

4) Remove .git from Xcode project

```
rm -rf .git
git init
git add.
git remote add origin 'http://192.168.1.150/something/something'
git commit,push
```

Get the same error.

**More:**

1) If I enter wrong password when creating repository account in Xcode->preferences->accounts it says failed to connect. Meaning if username and pass are correct it connects and does not show any error there.

2) I was able to push and pull with iSVN, now it says "Please go to edit working copy for:'Project name' and set the password again"

3) In keychain I have 3 keys with correct passwords.

4)When I set up remote in Xcode like 
`http://192.168.1.150/something1/something2`
 it says "Xcode has modified the URL ..." and After than in account its displayed as `http://192.168.1.150/something1`

could that be the problem? 
When I try to commit. Error displays correct link with something1/something2

5)Same repo works for 2 other Linux machines, I am on Yosemite,Xcode 6

6) Yes I have tried restarting Xcode :).